# which role each Node does it play in linked list?

Tags: java, algorithm, oop, linked-list

Why each time we create new node `p.next` so we need to assign **null** to `this.next`? isn't always **null** any way? and which role does it play in `LinkedList` ?
if we try to print out `this.next` it will be **null** before we assign it to **null**.

```
System.out.println(this.next);
```

Result is **null**

Also if `p.next` point to the new `node` why we need to set `p = p.next` to point to the same node? if the purpose to set tail to p at last, can't we just set `tail = p.next` which is the last one after for loop is finished.

```
public class EnkeltLenketListe<T>{
private T value;
private Node<T> next;

private Node(T value, Node<T> next)
{
System.out.println(this.next);
    this.next = next;
    this.value = value;
}
}

private Node<T> head, tail;

public EnkeltLenketListe(T[] a)
{
this();

int i = 0; for (; i < a.length && a[i] == null; i++);

if (i < a.length)
{
    head = new Node<>(a[i], null);
    Node<T> p = head;

    for (i++; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != null)
        {
            p.next = new Node<>(a[i], null);
            p = p.next;
        }
    }
    tail = p;
}
}
```

Comment: What does `neste` refer to?

Comment: sorry I fix it. it was written in another language I just change it to English. neste = next in Norwegian language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why each time we create new node p.next so we need to assign null to this.next?

while adding and removing a nodes, we have to make sure that nodes don't point to unintended nodes. they might have pointing to some nodes.

> why we need to set p = p.next to point to the same node

to locate and maintain your position in the list while you are traversing the list, you start from head, and continue to remaining nodes.  if  `p=p.next`, how are going to traverse the list?

> can't we just set tail = p.next which is the last one after for loop is finished.

No, we can not because in this case `p.next` is equivalent to `p.p.next` because `p` was set to `p.next` inside the loop.  test it by adding the following before `tail=p`, you should get **null**

```
System.out.println(p.next);
```

Edited:

your list is  singly linked list which means every node except the tail should have a pointer to next node, you started with

```
head = new Node<>(a[i], null);
Node<T> p = head;
```

in this case `p` and `head` are pointing `Node 0` see image below. if the next NOde in the array is not null, let see what happens in the for loop

```
    p.next = new Node<>(a[i], null);
    p = p.next;
```

In this case `p.next` is pointing to `Node 1` (see image below), where as `p` which were pointing to `Node 0` is now set to point to  `Node 1`. so both are pointing to 'Node 1`. the last one:

```
tail = p;
```

You said that why don't we just `tail=p.next`? No, we can not because in this case `p.next` is equivalent to `p.p.next` because `p` was set to `p.next` inside the loop.

[image: singly linked list]

[read about singly linked list here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Linked%20Lists/linked%20lists.html)

Comment: to make sure that I understood it. p.next is an object creating nodes and p is a reference which refererer to the current node?

Comment: both `p` and `p.next` are references to object of `Node <T>`, `p` point to current node, where as `p.next` to next node.

Comment: can you please explain to me how `p.next` point to Node when its inside for loop and to `null` after for loop. as you mentioned in your answer I got null when I tested `p.next` before `tail = p` and I tested it inside for loop and I got address to Node so what changed that `p.next`  become `null` after for loop ?

Comment: if there is `p.next` in side the loop and, you try `p.next` out side the loop, that is equivalent `p.next.next`

Answer (score 3):

Try to use contradiction. If you didn't set `p = p.next`, in the next iteration of the loop, again you will set the new node to the next position of the previous node. Hence, all the time `p` is the `head` and you didn't move the `p` anymore!

Therefore, you need to move `p` in each iteration after setting `p.next`. Indeed, it is a pointer to the last element of the list.

Comment: `p` maintains his position in the list while traversing .

Comment: yes my friend I got this but why we need `p`? we need to assign `tail` to the last node and the last node is the last one created in for loop, so can't we just after for loop set `tail = p.next`  ? so we dont need to set p = p.next in each iteration, do we ?

Comment: @husseinalbirouti `tail` is not enough. as you set `p.next` in each iteration, you should move `p` to avoid rewriting the future data on the previous,